# RodCutting: when the rod is bigger than the array length

Tags: java, dynamic-programming

How can I modify the methods cutRod and bottomUpCutRod to hold lengths that are bigger than the array length. For example, currently p has length 11, how can I cut the rod of length 15, 20 , etc, having this same array. For example

`p = {0, 1, 5, 8, 9, 10, 17, 17, 20, 24, 30};`

if I call cutRod(p,10), I get 30, but it crashes of course in cutRod(p,15) or
cutRod(p,20). (same applies for bottomUpCutRod). Any ideas how to do this?. This is dynamic programming problem, my idea to implement bottomUpCutRod method is to traverse p and for each element calculate every permutation of itself and its neighbors and update if necessary the resulting array, r.

```
 public class Main {    
    private static final double MINUS_INFINITY = Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;    

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // price array
        double[] p = {0, 1, 5, 8, 9, 10, 17, 17, 20, 24, 30};

        // test cutRod
        cutRod(p,10);

        // test bottomUpCutRod
       bottomUpCutRod(p,10);

    }//end of main

    // an optimal cut for a rod of length n
    // p is the price array
    // use recursion
    private static double cutRod(double[] p, int value) {
        double[] r = new double[value+1];
        double out = 0;

          // initialize r to NEGATIVE_INFINITY;
        for (int i = 1; i < r.length; i++)
            r[i] = MINUS_INFINITY;

        // call the helper method
        out = helpCutRod(p,r.length-1,r);

        // print r
        System.out.println("Result ");
        System.out.println("r[" + (r.length-1) + "] = " + r[r.length-1]);

        return out;
    }//end of method             

    // helpCutRod computes an optimal cut for a rod 
    // p is the price array and r[i] is the optimal cut for a rod of length i
    // n is the length of the rod that is currently being computed

    private static double helpCutRod(double[] p, int n, double[] r) {
        double q = MINUS_INFINITY;
        if (r[n] >= 0)  // the whole r was computed
            return r[n];
        if (n == 0)
           q = 0;
        else {
            for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {                
                 q = RodCutting.max(q, p[i] + helpCutRod(p,n-i,r));
            }    
            r[n] = q;
        }           
        return q;
    }                

    // use the bottom-up approach
    // do NOT use recursion

    private static double bottomUpCutRod(double[] p, int len) {
        // r[i] is the optimal cut for a rod of length i
        double[] r = new double[len+1];
        r[0] = 0;
        for (int j = 1; j < p.length; j++) {

            // compute r[j]
            double q = MINUS_INFINITY;

            // r[j] is the maximum over i of p[i] + r[j-i]
            // where 1<= i <= j

            for (int i = 1; i <= j; i++)                
                q = max(q, p[i] + r[j-i]);

            // update value of r[j]
            r[j] = q;
        }//end of for outer    

        // print r 
        System.out.println("The r array from the bottomUpCutRod:");
            System.out.println("r[" + len + "] = " + r[len]);
        return r[len] ;       
    }//end of method
    public static double max(double a, double b){

        if(a<=b){
            return b;
        }else{
            return a;
        }   
    }//end of max
}//end of class
```

Comment: Perhaps by checking whether your index is greater than the length of the array before trying to access it?

Comment: yes I can avoid this crash, but what I'm trying to solve is the algorithm to work for any length, how to cut any rod of length n.

Comment: @MarkDwayne *"https://code-industry.net/free-pdf-editor/"* aks the array for its lenght maby?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the rod cutting problem correctly, your price array, `p`, tells the prices at which you can sell rod pieces of lenghts 0 through `p.length - 1`. So if the array length is 11, you know the prices of pieces up to length 10 even if you have an inital rod of length 15, 20 or 30. Since you don’t know the prices for lengths 11 and above, I assume you can safely set them to 0. I would then expect the algorithm to cut up your rod into pieces for which you know a positive price.

If all of this is correct, the solution is easy. To calculate, say, `cutRod(p, 15)`, first do

```
    p = Arrays.copyOf(p, 15 + 1);
```

This will copy `p` into a new array with indices 0 through 15, padded with zeores. Now run your methods. Similarly for other initial lengths, of course.

With this modification, your program prints for a rod length of 15:

```
Result 
r[15] = 43.0
The r array from the bottomUpCutRod:
r[15] = 43.0
```

I assume it’s found pieces at 10, 3 and 2 yielding prices 30 + 8 + 5 = 43, but I haven’t checked.

EDIT: If the rod is very much longer than the price array, it is probably wasteful to have it calculate results with cuts longer than the maximum of the price array. So instead of the above quick fix, it is in fact possible to modify your methods to accept a shorter price array and a longer initial rod.

In the recursive `helpCutRod()`, change the for loop to:

```
        for (int i = 1; i <= Math.min(n, p.length - 1); i++) {
```

This will make sure that only pieces for which we have prices will be considered.

For `bottomUpCutRod()`, two changes are needed:

The first for loop needs to run until `j` equals `len`:

```
    for (int j = 1; j < r.length; j++) {
```

And again, the inner for loop should not pass the bounds of `p`:

```
        for (int i = 1; i <= Math.min(j, p.length - 1); i++)
```

With these three modifications instead of the extension of the `p` array, the program prints the same results as above.

Comment: There are a lot of permutations based on this example but I have 44 so far which is bigger than 43. This is not the final solution but I'm pretty sure it exists more than 44 as well. I get 44 if: 3+4+4+4=15 in terms of prices: 8+9+9+9=44.

Comment: Excuse me, 8 + 9 + 9 + 9 = 35, not 44.

Comment: I doubt you can have 44 and I am sure you cannot have 45 or more for an initial length of 15. 45 would equal 3 currency units per length unit, and the only way to have that is to sell only pieces at 10 length units at 30 price units. Since 10 doesn’t divide into 15, this is not possible,

Comment: my bad, I made too many calculations which resulted adding an extra 9. Yeah it is 35. So it seems to work now, thanks a lot @Ole V.V.